# Django Mutllevel foreign keys Admin Editor

Tags: django, foreign-keys, admin

I have Country/State/City models.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127)

class State(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127)

class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127)
```

All of them are `register`ed. I want to add/edit/delete all of them in Admin Editor.

Now, when I want to add a new `City`, I naturally will have to select the `State` and `Country` from the drop-down list.

But in the current condition, if I select a particular `Country`, all the `State`s are showing up including those that do not belong to the selected `Country`.

I want the available options in the drop-down lists to abide by the selections.

How can I achieve that for the Admin in the simplest way?

Thanks

Comment: `City` only has a `ForeignKey` to `State`, the code you have shown would suggest that there would __only__ be a `State` dropdown when creating a new `City`

Comment: @IainShelvington I have updated it.

Comment: This package might help https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/